# Twilo Message Broadcast

Tags: message, twilio, broadcast, voicemail

Hi all dose anybody have any simple basic workings  to send a prerecorded message to a phone like a broadcast using Twiillo

1. Make a call to a phone number
2. User picks up
3. Twilo plays a message
4. the users select a option Yes or No
   Hangs up

also how can we determine if its a voice mail box if the user dose not pick up and goes into if a voice mail

I am using PHP and have fair idea on what to call

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid playing messages to answering machines is to have a simple human-detector ('press 1 to hear the message').

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/can-twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine

The workflow sounds very doable by Twilio. I'm not a php programmer, but Twilio has a lot of documentation with examples in php. I'd check out the following if I were you:

to make a call

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

you're going to probably want to start a gather before playing the message as some people will reply before the message finishes

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather

and here's how to play

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play

alternatively if you want to use the TTS you can use the say tag instead

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say